# pts.js: Speed up animation of grid cells?

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm using [Pts.js](https://ptsjs.org/) to create a grid of cells and then color these cells depending on their distance to the mouse pointer. My code is largely based on [a demo from the official Pts.js Website](https://ptsjs.org/demo/edit/?name=create.gridcells).

```js
Pts.quickStart("#pt", "#123");
//
let pts = [];
var follower = new Pt();

space.add({
  start: (bound) => {
    pts = Create.gridCells(space.innerBound, 40, 20);
    follower = space.center;
  },
  //
  animate: (time, ftime) => {
    follower = follower.add(space.pointer.$subtract(follower).divide(20));
    form.stroke("#123");
    //
    let rects = pts.map((p) => {
      let color;
      let mag = follower.$subtract(Rectangle.center(p)).magnitude();
      let r = Rectangle.fromCenter(Rectangle.center(p), Rectangle.size(p));
      //
      if (mag >= 100) {
        color = "#000"
      } else {
        color = "#f00"
      }
      //
      form.fill(color).rect(r);
    })
    //
    form.fillOnly("#fff").point(space.pointer, 10, "circle");
  }
})
//
space.bindMouse().bindTouch().play();
```

```css
#pt {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/pts@0.9.4/dist/pts.min.js"></script>

<div id="pt"></div>
```

The implementation works absolutely fine. But I'd like to increase the speed with which the »coloring« of the cells »follows« the cursor, i.e. reduce the delay with which the red space around the cursor is animated. Ideally, I'd like to have no delay.

I'm new to Pts.js, so still wrapping my head around the docs, and I can't find an option or explanation for how to control the animation's speed. If anyone could point me to what I need to do here, that'd be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this line is what controls the behavior of the red grid area:

```
follower = follower.add(space.pointer.$subtract(follower).divide(20));
```

The value supplied to `.divide()` controls the speed at which the red area follows the cursor. Changing its argument from `20` to `1` (or even removing `.divide(20)` entirely) causes the "following" behavior to be immediate.

(Though, if you intend to remove the capability for that behavior, I suspect that entire line could be simplified.)

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. Can you explain why/how this value controls the speed?

Comment: @JoSch I'm guessing they track the red center independently (as `follower`) and update it by adding a fraction of the difference between it and the cursor position. The `.divide(20)` means the update moves the red center by 1/20th of the current distance each frame. By changing `20` to `1`, it's caused to move the entire distance in one frame.